# Css bundling with dot in virtual path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Kendo configurator installed its css content into "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.226" folder. I need to create the same virtual path in the mvc bundler in order to make it work (see http://www.telerik.com/forums/asp-mvc-css-minification-breaks-kendo-bootstrap).

However, when I create the bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.226/kendo-css").Include(
            "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.226/kendo.common.min.css",
            "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.226/kendo.default.min.css"));
```

I get 403 Forbidden response. Is there a way to make a virtual path containing dot work?

We use .net 4.6.1 and asp mvc 5.

---

*Obviously, the fallback is to rename the folder and all the paths, but I am asking if there is another way.*

Comment: In your project the css files are physically inside of the `Content/kendo/2016.1.226/` folder, right?

Comment: Yes and in subfolders like `Content/kendo/2016.1.226/Bootstrap/`

Comment: Then it shouldn't be a problem....I think the problem is because the .Net bundle doesn't like already minified files....try changing your file names in order to remove `min` from the filename like rename `kendo.common.min.css` to `kendo.common.css`(the same with the other file.....then in your bundle `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo-css").Include(
            "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.226/kendo.common.css",
            "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.226/kendo.default.css"));`

Comment: The problem is that I only have the minified files, so that would not work in debug mode.

Comment: Yeah, no problem, just change the names of the files; that way we are going to cheat the .net bundle and it's going to work

Comment: That would probably work, but it seems like a bit of a troll solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the name of your bundle (`~/Content/kendo/2016.1.226/kendo-css`) contains the same path as a physical path.

I would recommend changing your bundle name to something like `~/css/kendo` or the like.

You should also use the rewriting then to fix the URLs, for example:

```
.Include("~/content/css/menusprites.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
```

More can be found in this Telerik forum post: http://www.telerik.com/forums/asp-mvc-css-minification-breaks-kendo-bootstrap#KBg1hY3Z1EqbutQZxshjow

Comment: That breaks the `url(...)` calls in the css files, so your solution is not usable because you would have to have two sets of urls for debug without bundling and release with bundling.

Comment: @Santhos I have updated my answer incorporating the answer from your originally linked Telerik forum post.

Comment: It actually works, I am not sure why I haven't noticed that. I am not sure whether this is the best way to solve it, but it seems to work. I am also thinking if this should be the way to include all css files (just to be sure the paths are ok).